# find if user account is enabled or disabled in AD

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I need to find if user account is enabled or disabled in AD.

i Cant find the flag or property **"userAccountControl"**.
is this can be achieved using USERPRINCIPAL class?

```
        drop_persona1.Items.Clear();
        string valor = drop_area.SelectedValue;

            List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

       PrincipalContext ctx2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xxxxxxxx",
                                                        valor);


            UserPrincipal qbeUser2 = new UserPrincipal(ctx2);
            qbeUser2.Enabled = true; // activo para autenticacion

            PrincipalSearcher srch2 = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser2);
            srch2.QueryFilter = qbeUser2;    

            foreach (var found2 in srch2.FindAll().OrderBy(x=> x.DisplayName))
            {
                ListItem lst_user = new ListItem(found2.DisplayName, found2.SamAccountName);
                drop_persona1.Items.Insert(drop_persona1.Items.Count, lst_user);
            }

        //}
    }
```

Regards

Comment: ` qbeUser2.Enabled = true;` should be enough.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had not tested this answer but I believe it should work.

**1)** Get directory entry object using -

```
UserPrincipal qbeUser2 = new UserPrincipal(ctx2);
var dirEntry = qbeUser2.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
```

**2)** Then check for account disable status by -

```
var status = IsAccountDisabled(dirEntry);
public static bool IsAccountDisabled(DirectoryEntry user)
        {
            string Uac = "userAccountControl";
            if (user.NativeGuid == null) return false;

            if (user.Properties[Uac] != null && user.Properties[Uac].Value != null)
            {
                var userFlags = (UserFlags)user.Properties[Uac].Value;
                return userFlags.Contains(UserFlags.AccountDisabled);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

**3)** Here is the enum *UserFlags* -

```
[Flags]
public enum UserFlags
{
    // Reference - Chapter 10 (from The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming)

    Script = 1,                                     // 0x1
    AccountDisabled = 2,                            // 0x2
    HomeDirectoryRequired = 8,                      // 0x8
    AccountLockedOut = 16,                          // 0x10
    PasswordNotRequired = 32,                       // 0x20
    PasswordCannotChange = 64,                      // 0x40
    EncryptedTextPasswordAllowed = 128,             // 0x80
    TempDuplicateAccount = 256,                     // 0x100
    NormalAccount = 512,                            // 0x200
    InterDomainTrustAccount = 2048,                 // 0x800
    WorkstationTrustAccount = 4096,                 // 0x1000
    ServerTrustAccount = 8192,                      // 0x2000
    PasswordDoesNotExpire = 65536,                  // 0x10000 (Also 66048 )
    MnsLogonAccount = 131072,                       // 0x20000
    SmartCardRequired = 262144,                     // 0x40000
    TrustedForDelegation = 524288,                  // 0x80000
    AccountNotDelegated = 1048576,                  // 0x100000
    UseDesKeyOnly = 2097152,                        // 0x200000
    DontRequirePreauth = 4194304,                   // 0x400000
    PasswordExpired = 8388608,                      // 0x800000 (Applicable only in Window 2000 and Window Server 2003)
    TrustedToAuthenticateForDelegation = 16777216,  // 0x1000000
    NoAuthDataRequired = 33554432                   // 0x2000000
}
```

### *Update*

Here is the full code which is tested on AD. It worked fine in my testing.

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace DisableUsers
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        const string sAMAccountName = "vikas"; // The sAMAccountName of AD user
        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainNameHere", "AdminUser", "AdminPass");
        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, sAMAccountName);

        if (userPrincipal != null)
        {
            var dirEntry = userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            var status = IsAccountDisabled(dirEntry);
            Console.WriteLine(status ? "Account {0} is disabled." : "Account {0} is enabled.", sAMAccountName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No user found for sAMAccountName '{0}'.", sAMAccountName);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool IsAccountDisabled(DirectoryEntry user)
    {
        const string uac = "userAccountControl";
        if (user.NativeGuid == null) return false;

        if (user.Properties[uac] != null && user.Properties[uac].Value != null)
        {
            var userFlags = (UserFlags)user.Properties[uac].Value;
            return userFlags.Contains(UserFlags.AccountDisabled);
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public static class UserFlagExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if flags contains the specific user flag. This method is more efficient compared to 'HasFlag()'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="haystack">The bunch of flags</param>
    /// <param name="needle">The flag to look for.</param>
    /// <returns>Return true if flag found in flags.</returns>
    public static bool Contains(this UserFlags haystack, UserFlags needle)
    {
        return (haystack & needle) == needle;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum UserFlags
{
    Script = 1,                                     // 0x1
    AccountDisabled = 2,                            // 0x2
    HomeDirectoryRequired = 8,                      // 0x8
    AccountLockedOut = 16,                          // 0x10
    PasswordNotRequired = 32,                       // 0x20
    PasswordCannotChange = 64,                      // 0x40
    EncryptedTextPasswordAllowed = 128,             // 0x80
    TempDuplicateAccount = 256,                     // 0x100
    NormalAccount = 512,                            // 0x200
    InterDomainTrustAccount = 2048,                 // 0x800
    WorkstationTrustAccount = 4096,                 // 0x1000
    ServerTrustAccount = 8192,                      // 0x2000
    PasswordDoesNotExpire = 65536,                  // 0x10000 (Also 66048 )
    MnsLogonAccount = 131072,                       // 0x20000
    SmartCardRequired = 262144,                     // 0x40000
    TrustedForDelegation = 524288,                  // 0x80000
    AccountNotDelegated = 1048576,                  // 0x100000
    UseDesKeyOnly = 2097152,                        // 0x200000
    DontRequirePreauth = 4194304,                   // 0x400000
    PasswordExpired = 8388608,                      // 0x800000 (Applicable only in Window 2000 and Window Server 2003)
    TrustedToAuthenticateForDelegation = 16777216,  // 0x1000000
    NoAuthDataRequired = 33554432                   // 0x2000000
}
}
```

Comment: {"The Principal object must be persisted before this method can be called."} 
Sytem.InvalidOperation Exception--- in var dirEntry = qbeUser2.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

Comment: @IvanDiaz I had updated the answer. Hope it to work as it work on my end.

Comment: Is there any possibility to check the status without using "userAccountControl" ?

Comment: @Shesha I am not aware of any other way. However did you tried below solution provided by Brian Overby?

Comment: The property name "userAccountControl" didn't work for me on the latest Windows 10 update version. It seems they renamed it to "UserFlags". The values/flags of "UserFlags" work the very same way as described here.

Answer (score 16):

If you just need to find out if user is enabled or disable you can do it a bit simpler with the following:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, searchTextBox.Text.Trim());

if(user.Enabled == true) MessageBox.Show("Account enabled!");
else MessageBox.Show("Account disabled!");
```

Comment: So far in my testing, this seems to work the same as the first answer and performs better. I have code that queries an OU for all users and groups and checks their disabled status. One environment has about 40,000 users. I tried both the accepted answer and this one. The performance of the accepted answer was about 80 minutes. The performance for this answer was 1 minute.

Comment: do you need Administrator permission for this operation ?

Comment: Also, dont be confused when you see
`user.Enabled == true`
you really have to write it like this.
`if(user.Enabled)` won't work, since Enabled property is _nullable_.