# Interaction with TFS 2015 (On-Premise)

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015

I am creating an export file with all TFS projects, users and their associated TFS Groups for a specific TFS Collection. (using ITeamProjectCollectionService, IIdentityManagementService)

I noticed I receive also the disabled AD-users.  How can I filter the disabled AD-users out of this list? I have no direct access to the AD-environment.
The Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Identity does not contain this property.

```
        Uri configurationServerUri = new Uri(environmentConfig.Uri);
        TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(configurationServerUri);
        var tpcService = configurationServer.GetService<ITeamProjectCollectionService>();
        foreach (TeamProjectCollection tpc in tpcService.GetCollections())
        {
            var tfsProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(environmentConfig.Uri + "/" + tpc.Name), environmentCredential);

            var vcs = tfsProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var sec = tfsProjectCollection.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

            var teamProjects = vcs.GetAllTeamProjects(false);
            foreach (var teamProject in teamProjects)
            {
                var appGroups = sec.ListApplicationGroups(teamProject.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);

                foreach (var group in appGroups)
                {
                    Identity[] groupMembers = sec.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, new string[] { group.Sid }, QueryMembership.Expanded);
                    foreach (Identity member in groupMembers)
                    {
                        if (member.Members != null)
                        {
                            foreach (string memberSid in member.Members)
                            {
                                Identity memberInfo = sec.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, memberSid, QueryMembership.Expanded);
                                if (memberInfo.Type != IdentityType.WindowsUser)
                                    continue;

                                result.Add(new TfsPermission { Collection = tfsProjectCollection.Name, TeamProject = teamProject.Name,
                                    User = memberInfo.AccountName, Domain = memberInfo.Domain, Group = group.DisplayName });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Added the code.  We loop over every identity and add them to a List.  The function returns the list of identities. 
I'd like to filter out the users that are disabled in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `memberInfo.Domain == "DomainName"` to judge if this account is an AD account. Usually, if an identity is an windows account that added in TFS, it `memberInfo.Domain` property equals a server name not the domain name.

```
foreach (string memberSid in member.Members)
{
      Identity memberInfo = sec.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, memberSid, QueryMembership.Expanded);
      if (memberInfo.Type == IdentityType.WindowsUser && memberInfo.Domain == "DomainName")
      {
                                result.Add(new TfsPermission
                                {
                                    Collection = tfsProjectCollection.Name,
                                    TeamProject = teamProject.Name,
                                    User = memberInfo.AccountName,
                                    Domain = memberInfo.Domain,
                                    Group = group.DisplayName
                                });
       }
}
```

Then to check if those account is disabled in AD, like Starain said, using TFS API couldn't do that. But you could use this method below could help you check each account you get above if it is disable in AD: [find if user account is enabled or disabled in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358482/find-if-user-account-is-enabled-or-disabled-in-ad)

```
const string accountName = "name"; // The accountName of AD user
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainNameHere", "AdminUser", "AdminPass");
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, accountName);

if (userPrincipal != null)
{
    var dirEntry = userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
    var status = IsAccountDisabled(dirEntry);

}

//Jugde if it is disabled in AD
public static bool IsAccountDisabled(DirectoryEntry user)
{
        const string uac = "userAccountControl";
        if (user.NativeGuid == null) return false;

        if (user.Properties[uac] != null && user.Properties[uac].Value != null)
        {
            var userFlags = (UserFlags)user.Properties[uac].Value;
            return userFlags.Contains(UserFlags.AccountDisabled);
        }

        return false;
}
```

However, the `memberInfo.Type` could only distinguish the Identity is an user account or a TFS group. As we all know, when you set the permissions of someone, you will choose to add an account or a TFS group. 
[image]

Comment: Indeed. Thank you but how can you know the AD account is disabled?

Comment: @Jens You can't know whether the AD account is disabled or not by using TFS API. You need to use AD API to check the user state. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318857/how-to-check-in-c-sharp-if-user-account-is-active

Comment: @Jens I have edited by reply. TFS API doesn't have the method to exclude those disabled users.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I am using additional code now to detect the status of the users.

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT yes, working with the AD API's did the trick.  Thanks for the feedback